# re-authentication FB Unity C#

Tags: c#, facebook, unityscript

The only problem that I have is when I try to re-authenticate the app.

I can access all the information without problems, the profile pic, name, etc. All the info that I need, was stored on a local file. When I deleted the app, and installed it back, I tried to Login back on FB and FB gave me back an error that says I'm already logged in with this app.

How can I re-authenticate the app

Answer (score 0):

You might need to go to your facebook profile's settings and remove the app from there. Maybe this will help:
[How do I edit the privacy and settings for my apps and games?](https://www.facebook.com/help/218345114850283)

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the "Key Hash" that I have doesn't match with the one in my app, the solution was very simple, I just took the "Key Hash" that the app gave me back and added it to the "Key Hashes" on FB, after this the problem was solved on all the devices.

Just need to check carefully between the capital "I" and the "l", because they look similar.